# NG-ZORRO NzUpload How use NzDownload function

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

```
<nz-upload
          class="file-uploader"
          [nzCustomRequest]="customReq"
          [(nzFileList)]="fileList"
          [nzDownload]="downloadReq"
          [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload"
          (nzChange)="handleChange($event)"
  >
    <button tc-button [beforeIcon]="'icofont-upload-alt'" [type]="'button'">Click to upload</button>
  </nz-upload>
```

Typescript

```
downloadReq = (file: NzUploadFile) => {}
```

How use this method to request? File can be downloaded who has access. And I can't set header to download request. I use angular 9.

[Nz Upload](https://ng.ant.design/version/9.3.x/components/upload/en)

Comment: [I've found it](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/4570)
Thank you very much!)

Comment: Please post the actual answer here at SO. Just linking to an external site in the comment without some textual context is not the best way to answer your own question.